# Vectorisation of formula in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, formula

I am creating a comparison of vector to check whether it is of a Fibonacci sequence.

```
function f = fibo(n)
f(1)=7;
f(2)=9;
k=3:5;
f(k)=f(k-1)+f(k-2)
ans=isequal(n,f)
```

The output shows

```
f =
     7    9     16     9     0
```

instead of

```
7 9 16 25 41
```

how do i vectorise this part of the code?

```
if n == 1,
    f = 1;   % First element is 1.
    return;
elseif n == 2
    f = [1 1];  % First two elements are 1.
else
    % Call fibrec with previous result and compute next one from it.
    fm1 = fibrec(n-1); 
    f = [fm1 fm1(end)+fm1(end-1)];
end
```

Comment: I did not show the comparison vector as it is a input function.
my error lies with the formula given here. I need a correction to this formula to get the exact vector 7  9  16  25  41

Comment: I understand that when k = 3, i(1), i(2) are taken into account but when k = 4, k = 5 it doesn't add up previous i(k-1) + i(k-2)

Comment: As is, your code returns an error: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` Do you initialise `i` as a vector before the code posted in your question? Please always post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yup. I did initialise

Comment: Apart from what @Jubobs said, the returned value `f` is never assigned in your function.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot vectorize an iterative procedure. If you want vectorization just for the lulz, you can instead use the direct formula for the *n*th Fibonacci number

```
>> f = @(n) round(1/sqrt(5) * (((1 + sqrt(5))/2).^n - ((1 - sqrt(5))/2).^n));
>> f(1:5)

ans = 

    1    1    2    3    5
```

The calculations in `f` are wrapped by `round`, because we want the Fibonacci numbers to be integers, but `sqrt` returns doubles (thanks, Jubobs).

Beware that, even if this code is vectorized by MATLAB, the iterative procedure might still be faster.

Now, if you want to check whether an array `fibs` contains precisely the Fibonacci numbers from `j` to `k`, you can call

```
>> all(f(j:k) == fibs(:)')
```

where `fibs(:)'` casts the vector into a row vector. For example,

```
>> j = 5;
>> k = 10;
>> fibs = [5 8 13 31 34 55];
>> all(f(j:k) == fibs(:)')

ans = 

     1
```

Comment: for an input of random vectors to check if it is of 'fibonacci sequence' which can be any other numbers like 3 4 7 11 18

Comment: @Executor345 I don’t understand you. You can call `f(121)` or `f([1 42 17 3])` just as well.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that you get doubles (`1.0000`) instead of "integers" (`1`); that won't fly if a comparison with a vector of "integers" is to be performed. You should add some rounding inside the definition of your `f` function.